# add and calculate percentage

Tags: gawk, numeric-data

I have two columns of data, I want add the number of repeating records in column A and then calculate the number of tallies in column B and then calculate the percentage of tallies.  Example:

```
494   1
494
494
494   1
500
500   1
500
501
501
501  1
501
```

For 494, there are 4 records and 2 tallies, so I would like to calculate 2/4 = .50  and so on.

Comment: Is the input always sorted (or at least collated) on the first column (which is sometimes the only column)?  Is the second column always either `1` or blank?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Great that you've detailed the input.  Could you update the question to clearly show desired output ?

Answer (score 1):

As a one-liner this `awk` example is rather complicated.

```
{
  if (A!=$1) {   # This section has a different A-column
    if (a) {       # If a>0, then it is not the beginning
      print A,b/a  # Print result
    }
    A=$1;          # Re-init variables
    a=0;
    b=0
  }
  ++a;
  b += $2 ? 1 : 0
}
```

To run this, put the awk script in `frac-calc` and the numbers in `number` and run it:

```
( cat number; echo ) | awk -E frac-calc
```

The output would be:

```
494 0.5
500 0.333333
501 0.25
```

The reason why the `echo` is needed, is that it ensure the result of the last block (501) to be printed, as column A is different.

It can also be a long one-liner:

```
( cat number; echo ) | awk '{if(A!=$1){if(a){print A,b/a}A=$1;a=0;b=0}++a;b+=$2?1:0}'
```

**Edit**: With the use of `END` and without `echo` as mentioned in the comments:

```
{
  if (A!=$1) {   # This section has a different A-column
    if (a) {       # If a>0, then it is not the beginning
      print A,b/a  # Print result
    }
    A=$1;          # Re-init variables
    a=0;
    b=0
  }
  ++a;
  b += $2 ? 1 : 0
}
END {
      print A,b/a  # Print result
}
```

And call it:

```
awk -E frac-calc number
```

The one liner is then a bit longer:

```
awk '{if(A!=$1){if(a){print A,b/a}A=$1;a=0;b=0}++a;b+=$2?1:0}END{print A,b/a}' number
```

Comment: Why the `cat` and `echo`?  Why not just `awk ... number`?

Comment: Because the the last set (501) will not get calculated before there is a line without 501. One could also add an extra line to the file like `echo >> number`.

Comment: That's what `END` is for.

Answer (score 0):

#### First version - the two dimensional array is used.

```
gawk '
BEGIN {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc";
}
{
    arr[$1][0]++;
    arr[$1][1] += $2;
}
END {
    for(i in arr) {
        print i, arr[i][1] / arr[i][0];
    }
}' input.txt
```

The `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc";` line is explained here - [Using Predefined Array Scanning Orders](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Scanning).

In this case, it can be replaced by piping the `gawk` output to the `sort -n` command:

```
gawk '
{
    arr[$1][0]++;
    arr[$1][1] += $2;
}
END {
    for(i in arr) {
        print i, arr[i][1] / arr[i][0];
    }
}' input.txt | sort -n
```

#### Second version - more optimal variant, without array.

```
gawk '
NR == 1 { 
    record = $1;
}
record != $1 {
    print record, tallies / cnt;    
    record = $1;
    cnt = 0;
    tallies = 0;
}
{
    cnt++;
    tallies += $2;
}
END {
    print record, tallies / cnt;    
}' input.txt
```

**Output:**

```
494 0.5
500 0.333333
501 0.25
```